# Maximum verbosity in Memcheck?

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

From my experimentation it looks to me like the furthest maximum meaningful verbosity in Valgrind's Memcheck is two `--verbose` flags<sup>1</sup>.

Is that true?

<sub>1: Three or more `--verbose` flags would be allowed, but I think they make no substantial change in the output.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give as many -v options as your want.

Most of the verbosity usage are comparing with verbosity 1 or 2,
but there are a number of comparisons with verbosity 3.
I found no code checking verbosity 4 or above.